# Getting push event added file name in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

I need to read file zip file name in GitHub actions. But in following code, both Artifact and Artifact1 are returning blank values. What is wrong with the code?

```
name: SCR Initial

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'test/**zip'

jobs:
  SCR:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Artifact zip name
        run: |
          echo "Commit text = ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}"
          echo "Artifact name= ${{ github.event.head_commit.added }}"
          echo "Artifact1 name = ${{ github.event.head_commit.added[0] }}"
```

I have checked in workflow logs and able to see blank.

Answer (score 0):

In a `push` event triggering a github actions workflow, the `head_commit` object payload doesn't contain those `message` and `added` fields.

This [head_commit](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2#file-github-context-push-json-L45) object is filled as follow (example from a personal repository):

```
{
...
    "head_commit": {
      "author": {
        "email": "guillaume.falourd@zup.com.br",
        "name": "GuillaumeFalourd",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd"
      },
      "private": false,
      "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/pulls{/number}",
      "pushed_at": 1624727244,
      "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/releases{/id}",
      "size": 230,
      "ssh_url": "git@github.com:GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
      "stargazers": 2,
      "stargazers_count": 2,
      "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/stargazers",
      "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/statuses/{sha}",
      "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/subscribers",
      "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/subscription",
      "svn_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
      "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/tags",
      "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/teams",
      "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/trees{/sha}",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-26T17:05:58Z",
      "url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
      "watchers": 2,
      "watchers_count": 2
    },
...
}
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/81f41fb8b53a0bd3d63856f919e501c2#file-github-context-push-json) is an example of a full `push` event JSON if you want to check its structure.

To access the last push commit message for example, you would need to use `${{ github.event.commits.[0].message }}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ${{ github.event.commits.[0].message }} is giving the commit message but I need to access the name of the file which is uploaded in the repository with the same push.

Comment: `Teemu Risikko` shared a way to get those file names in the other answer. You would probably need a script to check if a specific file is among them to perform some customizable operation.

Answer (score 0):

`${{ github.event.head_commit.added }}` does not exist any more, see [this blog post](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-10-16-changes-in-github-actions-push-event-payload/) for more information.

In addition to what GuiFalourd already said, you can do something like this:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only HEAD~1
```

This will list only the files that were added (`=A`) in the latest commit.